# Uploading files to a teamspeak server

Tags: java, telnet

I'm currently trying to create a Java Library which communicates with teamspeak servers using server query commands over telnet, and I came across the following problem:
When I'm trying to upload a file to the server I need to execute a command to get a file transfer key (ftinitupload), but now I don't know how to upload a file using the transfer key, as this simple way isn't working:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(tshost, 30033);
OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
socketOutputStream.write(ftkey.getBytes());
socketOutputStream.write(imageInByte);
```

Does anyone of you maybe know how to upload a file using java?

Comment: This isnt so much as a question of how to do it in java as how does teamspeak transfer files. I found this forum http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/46659-File-Transfer Also this http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/50203-Help-with-file-transfer-upload-through-telnet-(ftinitupload)

Comment: You are right, but I honestly had no idea where to find help... teamspeak in the teamspeak forum nobody seems to know the answer. Something I've found is this https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/class_team_speak3___adapter___file_transfer.html#a9cf1d5542573d87ad5513e4e3eed6b8a maybe someone could help me understanding it?

Comment: Is anyone maybe familiar with wireshark and can tell help me if I upload wireshark logs?